# how to declare null value to integer in android

Tags: java, integer

I want to know how I should declare a Integer with Null Value in Android.
Here is my code:

```
btnload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String getDate, getEpayee, getEcategory;
            int getEamt;
            getDate= "";

            getEamt="";  //This Eamt variable is of integer type and
                                       //this gives me a error.

            getEpayee ="";
            getEcategory="";
```

Comment: You only can set to 0.

Comment: use Integer for setting null

Answer (score 5):

`int` is a primitive type in Java; hence you cannot set it to `null` (it is not an object).

if `getEamt` is an `int`, you cannot initialize it to a `String`. If you really want to set an integer to `null` you need to use the `Integer` class.

Comment: If you want to set it to 0, yes.

Comment: there is always the possibility to use Integer

Comment: If you use the `Integer` class you can set it to any integer you want and also set it to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some kind of "default" or initialization value with the int type, you might consider starting to count at 1 and interpret 0 or a negative int as the default value.

Comment: yes thanx. i wanted to keep a default value and then update it with entered user value

Answer (score 0):

You have probably miss understand what `null` is.

In the example you have posted you use *empty string* `""`. So you can initialize String instances to avoid `NullPointerException`. In case you do not initialize (assign at declaration) any value you have `null` value by default for Object types.

`String message;` is equal to `String message = null;`

What your are doing by `String message = ""` is that you set a reference to empty string.

---

The `null` is applicable only for Object types not [primitive ones](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). How ever each primitive has a wrapper class that allow null.

You can do this

`Integer value = null;`

You **can not** do this

`int value = null;`

In general you should avoid the `null`. Usage of primitive assure that you will never pass a null.

As in your code the declaration are local you should declare them just before usage with valid value instead of create a section of initialization and then a block of usage.

```
btnload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           conductPaymentTransaction()
        }

private void conductPaymentTransaction() 
{

 Date          date = getDate();
 EPayee        paye = getEPayee()
 ECategory category = getECategory();
 int        ammount = getAmmount();

 //...

}
```

Note: you should not store your data structure in form of plain string.